# Get coordinates from a clipping object in webgl with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Good day everyone.
I have a question which is based on this GitHub project:

https://github.com/daign/clipping-with-caps

I'm testing this project for the clipping.
Here would it be the demo: (Link in the comments)

Here is the question: I need to get from the actual clipping, the world position values(x,y,z) of the plane who is temporarily clipped.
In this picture, you can see what I need.

[image: Screenshot from demo with circled sections]

Every closed clipped plane have vertices. Is it possible to get these points? Is it possible to get these points divided by shape and by plane orientation?
Thank you for your attention. I hope the question is clear enough.
I have already tried to find a solution with the help of these post, but nothing close to what I need sadly.

[How to render clipped surfaces as solid objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090942/how-to-render-clipped-surfaces-as-solid-objects/37093210#37093210)

[How to render clipped surfaces as solid objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090942/how-to-render-clipped-surfaces-as-solid-objects/37093210#37093210)

[Three.JS Object Clipping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557486/three-js-object-clipping)

link to demo: http://daign.github.io/clipping-with-caps/

Thanks in advance for reading this, I'm open to every suggestion or solution.

Comment: Since I'm limited with the links, I will post them here: 
Link1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090942/how-to-render-clipped-surfaces-as-solid-objects/37093210#37093210

Comment: Link2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090942/how-to-render-clipped-surfaces-as-solid-objects/37093210#37093210

Comment: Link3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557486/three-js-object-clipping

Comment: Link demo: http://daign.github.io/clipping-with-caps/

Comment: Take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353447/4045502)

Comment: @prisoner849 thank you for reading and commenting, I am going to try it like that :)