# three js: find intersection between a mesh and a clipping plane

Tags: three.js, clipping, outline

I am using a moving clipping plane to explore the internal details of an object resulting from loading several meshes into the three js viewer:

[image]

I would like to draw an outline to highlight the line created by the intersection of the object with the (invisible) clipping plane. Any idea that can point me in the right direction to achieve my goal?

Comment: @genpfault Please do not add webgl tags to three.js questions unless the question is specifically about a webgl feature.

Comment: Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37593904/1461008) may be a workaround.

Comment: May be [this](https://gkjohnson.github.io/three-mesh-bvh/example/bundle/clippedEdges.html) solution can help